# Java SSLSockets: same keyStore on client and server, is it safe?

Tags: java, security, ssl, certificate, client

So I have an sslServer and an sslClient. I generate a certificate, put it into a keyStore, and plonk the keyStore into the server's main directory. I then copy this keyStore into the clients directory. Is that safe? Couldn't someone just download a copy of my client and get the certificate/keyStore and perform man in middle attacks? How could I fix this certificate sharing problem? If it helps here is some code:

Server:

```
/*This is a hidden class*/
class Server implements Runnable{
public Server(){

}
@Override
public void run() {
    DataInputStream stringGetter = null;
    try{
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

    char[] password = "iamakeystore".toCharArray();
    ks.load(null, password);

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "keyStore.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "iamakeystore");
    // Store away the keystore.
    //FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("keyStore.jks");
    //ks.store(fos, password);
    //fos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    SSLSocket sslsocket = null;
    try {
        SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory =
                (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLServerSocket sslserversocket =
                (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(31030);
        sslserversocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(sslserversocket.getSupportedCipherSuites());
        sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();



        stringGetter= new DataInputStream(sslsocket.getInputStream());
        boolean done=false;
        byte input=-1;

        while(!done){

            input=stringGetter.readByte();

        switch(input){
            case 1:{

            }
        }
        }
        sslsocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(stringGetter!=null){
            try {
                stringGetter.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(sslsocket!=null){
            try {
                sslsocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
}
```

Client:

```
private void login(){
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "keyStore.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "iamakeystore");
    SSLSocketFactory ssf = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLSocket s = null;
    DataOutputStream stringSender = null;

    try {
        s=(SSLSocket) ssf.createSocket("127.0.0.1", 31030);
        s.setEnabledCipherSuites(s.getSupportedCipherSuites());
        s.startHandshake();
        stringSender= new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stringSender.writeByte(1);

        stringSender.flush();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(s!=null){
            try {
                s.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `s.setEnabledCipherSuites(s.getSupportedCipherSuites())`: please don't do that on either side. You're enabling every supported cipher suites, including those that are not enabled by default because they're insecure.

Comment: @Bruno What alternatives are there? What can I use instead. Thank you for your support. Could you please point me at some tutorials or something?

Comment: Use the ones that are enabled by default (i.e. don't change the enabled cipher suites). You should only change the enabled cipher suites if you know which ones you want to enable and disable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I then copy this keyStore into the clients directory.

Don't.

> Is that safe?

No. It's both unsafe and pointless. The keystore contains a private key. It should therefore be private to the owner of the key. That means that the two key owners, client and server, should each have their own keytore. A private key that isn't private defeats its own purpose and makes PKI and everything that relies on it such as TLS completely insecure.

> Couldn't someone just download a copy of my client and get the certificate/keyStore and perform man in middle attacks?

Yes.

> How could I fix this certificate sharing problem?

Don't share it. Generate two keystores, two keypairs, two certificates, and use one at the server and one at the client. Don't mix them, don't confuse them, don't conflate them.

Comment: In addition, since client-cert authentication isn't used in this example, only one keypair and certificate needs to be generated. You'll just need to export that cert from the server keystore and import it in the truststore you're giving to the clients.

Answer (score 1):

Create  two certificate signed by a ca and keep there into each others truststore and save the private key in corresponding side keystore in this way you can achieve mutual authentication and defend against man in middle attack.